SwiftUI how to hide "more" navigation bar in 5th,6th tabs in a custom Tabview
I'm using a custom tabview to show 6 tabs in the tabview. It's only limited to 5 so if you add 6, it creates a "More" section and the 5th and 6th tabs are shown in a navigation view. When you view 5th,6th tabs, it shows a back navigation bar on top with "more". I got the tabview to show all 6 tabs without "more" option but when I view 5th, 6th tabs it still show a navigation bar on top with "more" back button. X has implemented this with 6th tabs without the extra navigation bar on the 5,6 tabs, so it's certainly possible.
Ideally I'm trying to hide the "more "navigation bar from the first view and keep the navigation bar of the actual view.
I have tried
                     View6()
                            .tag(Tab.home5)
                            .navigationBarTitle("")
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                            .navigationBarHidden(true)


Tabview
         VStack(spacing: 0){
                 TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                     View1()
                            .tag(Tab.home1)
                     View2()
                            .tag(Tab.home2)
                     View3()
                            .tag(Tab.home3)
                     View4()
                            .tag(Tab.home4)
                     View5()
                            .tag(Tab.home5)
                     View6()
                            .tag(Tab.home6)

                 }
 
                         TabBar()
                         .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                 
             }

Custom Tab builder (shows all 6 tabs instead of a more section on the 5th tab)
    @ViewBuilder
    func TabBar()->some View{
        
        HStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(Icons){icon in
                        
                        let tabColor: SwiftUI.Color = currentTab == icon.tabIcon ? (scheme == .dark ? .white : .black) : .gray.opacity(0.6)
                        
                        ResizableIconView(IconView: icon.View,color: tabColor)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical,10)
                .background {
                    (scheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
    }

When I view 5th,6th tabs, extra more navigation is shown as below,
more navigation bar
I tried setting navigationBarBackButtonHidden to true but it doesn't work. I've also tried hiding the navigation bar globally but this removes all navigation bars from alll tabs.
extension UINavigationController {
    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
}



I think the solution is UIKit related

Yes, the answer is basically UIKit. You should wrap a UITabBarController and set its moreNavigationController.isNavigationBarHidden to true.
I have combined this answer that shows a simple wrapper around a UITabBarController with this answer about the correct timing to set isNavigationBarHidden:
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        moreNavigationController.delegate = self
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // hide the nav bar here:
        navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
}

struct TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var controllers: [UIViewController]

    @Binding var switchTab: Int

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomTabBarController {
        let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController()
        tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true // hide the tab bar here
        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
        tabBarController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return tabBarController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomTabBarController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.selectedIndex = switchTab
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
        let owner: TabBarController
        init(_ owner: TabBarController) {
            self.owner = owner
        }
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
            owner.switchTab = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
struct UIKitStyleTabView: View {
    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<AnyView>]

    @Binding var switchTab: Int

    struct Tab {
        var view: AnyView
        var barItem: UITabBarItem

        init<V: View>(view: V, barItem: UITabBarItem) {
            self.view = AnyView(view)
            self.barItem = barItem
        }
    }

    init(_ tabs: [Tab], switchTab: Binding<Int>) {
        self.viewControllers = tabs.map {
            let host = UIHostingController(rootView: $0.view)
            host.tabBarItem = $0.barItem
            return host
        }
        self._switchTab = switchTab
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabBarController(controllers: viewControllers, switchTab: $switchTab)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

Example usage - this shows a 6-tabbed tab view, with a button in the first tab that brings you to the 6th tab.
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var switchTab: Int = 0

    let tabBarSymbolConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .medium)

    var body : some View {

        UIKitStyleTabView([
            UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Button("Go to tab 6") { self.switchTab = 5 }, barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Social", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            ), UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Text("SearchView"), barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            ), UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Text("WorkoutsView"),barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Workouts", image: UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard.fill", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            ), UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Text("ExercisesView"), barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Exercises", image: UIImage(systemName: "sportscourt", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            ), UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Text("AccountView"), barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Me", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            ), UIKitStyleTabView.Tab(view: Text("SomeOtherView"), barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Other", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle", withConfiguration: tabBarSymbolConfig)!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 4.5), selectedImage: nil)
            )
        ], switchTab: $switchTab)
    }
}


You can also use SwiftUI Introspect to get a UITabBarController from a TabView directly, but it can only introspect on the versions you specify, so it is not future-proof at all.
TabView(selection: $tab) {
    ForEach(0..<7) { i in
        Text("Tab \(i)").tabItem { Text("\(i)") }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}
.introspect(.tabView, on: .iOS(.v13, .v14, .v15, .v16, .v17)) { tabView in
    tabView.moreNavigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}


Thanks! is there a way I could keep my current tabbar and write a UIKit extension to just hide the first navigation bar when I go to 5th,6th tabs?

@URihal You can use SwiftUI Introspect to get a UITabBarController, and maybe you can do something similar with that. But this is not future-proof. With SwiftUI-Introspect, you must specify the versions of iOS that you want to introspect on, so it will stop working on newer versions unless SwiftUI Introspect releases a new version, and you update your app, and the user installs the update.

I like the Introspect approach. I got it working but it hides the navigation bar of the view and not the "more" navigation bar. Would you know how to change this?              View6()
.tag(Tab.home6)                                                  .introspect(.navigationView(style: .stack), on: .iOS(.v17)) { navigationController in
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

@URihal See the edit, You need to introspect .tabView and get its moreNavigationController.

A side question, this is the first time I incorporated a custom tabview. When I'm searching in the search tab, or whenever theres text input and the on screen keyboard pops up, the tabbar floats above the keyboard. What's the best way to hide the custom tabview when searching or typing? ( instead of checking if issearching, or typing then passing a $showtab bool through the tab to the view and changing it there, can I check if the on screen keyboard is on and if so disable the tabbar globally? )

@URihal How about .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) on the outer VStack? It might also work if you put it on the tab bar itself, but I'm not sure. I'd suggest posting this separately if you are still stuck.

It works! Brilliant! Have a wonderful day sir!
